# Array of embedded documents - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have these two MongoDB documents. I want to find the capacity of Real and Barcelona stadiums, supposing Real Madrid has two stadiums(sorry Merengues :)

```
{
      "_id" : "Bar.43",
      "official_name" : "Futbol Club Barcelona
      "country" : "Spain",
      "started_by" : {
              "day" : 28,
              "month" : 11,
              "year" : 1899
      },
      "stadium" : {
              "name" : "Camp Nou",
              "capacity" : 99354
      },
      "palmarès" : {
              "La Liga" : 23,
              "Copa del Rey" : 27,
              "Supercopa de Espana" : 11,
              "UEFA Champions League" : 4,
              "UEFA Cup Winners Cup" : 4,
              "UEFA Super Cup" : 4,
              "FIFA Club World cup" : 2
      },
      "uniform" : "blue and dark red"
},

{
      "_id" : "RMa.103",
      "official_name" : "Real Madrid Club de Fùtbol
      "country" : "Spain",
      "started_by" : {
              "day" : 6,
              "month" : 3,
              "year" : 1902
      },
      "stadium" : [{
              "name" : "Santiago Bernabeu",
              "capacity" : 85454
      },
                   {
               "name" : "Vicente Calderon"
               "capacity" : 54907
      }],
      "palmarès" : {
              "La Liga" : 32,
              "Copa del Rey" : 19,
              "Supercopa de Espana" : 9,
              "UEFA Champions League" : 10,
              "UEFA Europa League" : 2,
              "UEFA Super Cup" : 2,
              "FIFA Club World cup" : 4
      },
      "uniform" : "white"
}
```

Well, my query is:

```
db.team.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$country", capacityStadium:{$sum:"$stadium.capacity"}}}])
```

But it does not work. If Real Madrid has just one stadium, instead, my query works. So, in general, when I have an array of embedded documents and I want to use aggregations, must I use $unwind to divide documents of that array?
The problem is the field stadium of Barcelona is not an array of documents and the query gets an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to change your document structure because the `stadium` field should be a array across for in each document. To do that you need to find documents where stadium is not an array and update them using the "Bulk" operations for maximum efficiency

```js
var bulk = db.team.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;
db.team.find({ "stadium.0": { "$exists": false }}).forEach(function(doc) { 
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id })
        .updateOne({ "$set": { "stadium": [doc.stadium] }}); 
    count++; 
    if(count % 100 == 0) {     
    bulk.execute();     
    bulk = db.team.initializeOrderedBulkOp(); } })

if(count % 100 > 0) { 
    bulk.execute(); 
}
```

---

Now use the aggregation framework.

```js
db.team.aggregate(
    [
       { "$project": { "stadium.capacity": 1 }}, 
       { "$unwind": "$stadium" }, 
       { "$group": { "_id": "$_id", "totalCapacity": { "$sum": "$stadium.capacity" }}}
    ]
)
```

Which returns:

```js
{ "_id" : "RMa.103", "totalCapacity" : 140361 }
{ "_id" : "Bar.43", "totalCapacity" : 99354 }
```